# disable touch events of RecyclerView (to prevent user touches)?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView in my app and it displays data. I want to disable user touch events of RecyclerView. I have tried the below code but it does not work.

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: You can check this for touch event on each item. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.html

Comment: I would extend RecyclerView and Override the onTouch and onInterceptTouchEvent to always return false.

Answer (score 24):

As I had a similar use case a few days ago and stumbled upon this question just now:
you can add either

- [`RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener.html)
- or [`RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.html)

to your RecyclerView.

Example using `RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener`:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        // true: consume touch event
        // false: dispatch touch event
        return true;
   }
});
```

I consumed the touch event while my `SwipeRefreshLayout` was doing background work by querying `swipeLayout.isRefreshing()`.

Answer (score 12):

Java:

```java
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Kotlin:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(object : RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener() {
    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return true
    }
})
```

Just use this, fixed my problems (;

Comment: Note that with this method, not only you cannot touch, but also you cannot scroll.

Comment: This doesn't prevent touches, testing on Android Q. I set smooth scroll programatically, then touched while scrolling, and it stops.

Answer (score 9):

you can use RecyclerView function

`public void setLayoutFrozen(boolean frozen)`

Comment: are you sure ? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setLayoutFrozen(boolean)

Comment: `setLayoutFrozen(boolean frozen)` is deprecated, use `suppressLayout(boolean suppress)` instead.

Comment: When `suppressLayout(true)` invoked, `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` and `adapter.notifyItemChanged(int position)` not worked.

Answer (score 8):

If you return `true`  touch events are disabled.

if Return `false` touch events are enable.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
   }
});
```

hope it helps..

Answer (score 8):

You can use `yourRecyclerView.suppressLayout(true)` to disable user interaction

Comment: great its work like cham for my use case to disable touch event on my nested recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

You can override the LinearLayoutManager `canScrollHorizontally` method

```
getRecyclerView().setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) {
    @Override
    public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
        return false;
    }
});
```