# How disable user touch or scroll on recyclerview (autoscroll) Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, touch, autoscroll

I implement auto scroll on RecyclerView to display like running text using smoothScrollToPosition. And it is working.

```
public void autoScroll() {
    final int speedScroll = 1000;
    runnableRunningAds = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            rcRunningTextAds.smoothScrollToPosition(runningTextAdsAdapter.getItemCount());
            blnRunningAdsIsRunning = true;
            handlerRunningAds.postDelayed(this, speedScroll);
        }
    };
    handlerRunningAds.postDelayed(runnableRunningAds, speedScroll);
}
```

The problem is it stop scrolling when user touch the RecyclerView. I was already try [this,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38352285/3561155) but it is still not working. The RecyclerView still stop scrolling.

Any idea about it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using post delayed to work in a separate thread

```
private void disableTouch(){

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new 
             RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
                  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, 
                   MotionEvent e) {
                  // true: consume touch event
                 // false: dispatch touch event
        return true;
   }
});
        }
    }, 500);
}
```