# Remove the Recyclerview addOnItemTouchListner once one item is clicked?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener

i have list of some items and onclick of each item i am opening the alertdialog, but sometimes 2 dialoges are opened as two recyclerview's items are clicked at same time so to avoid this i think i should remove the addOnItemTouchListner, but how to remove it?

Comment: Better way would be setting a flag and checking if it is true or false in your onItemTouchListener.

Comment: but i think there their must be a proper way to handle this.

Comment: using boolean variable you can check for your own logic

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808992/disable-touch-events-of-recyclerview-to-prevent-user-touches

Comment: I arrive a little bit late in the discussion but, as it just happened to me, you can also in your conditions add the count of selectedItems. E.g. `if (actionMode != null && adapter.selectedCount == 1)`, normally at this time, you should not be able to select an another row if you already selected one.

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting up `OnClickListener` for the itemView in the ViewHolder implementation instead of `OnItemTouchListener` because `OnItemTouchListener` will call 2 times when you click on an itemView, for up and down actions

Try setting `OnClickListener` or check the actions in the `onTouchEvent()` method like

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      // do the dialog showing here
}
```

**EDIT**

```
 class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ...
        ...
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  //call the dialog here
                  // If you need context here use v.getContext() to show the dialog
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: this i have to add separately for particular recyclerview in my project

Comment: @NikhilJadhav What are you looking for, then?

Comment: a global solution that will work for all through out my project

Comment: Are you using the same adapter for all the RecyclerView?

Comment: If you are, then you could add OnClickListener to the itemView in the ViewHolder class' constructor

Comment: yes, with the help of data binding, tried to reduce the redundant code of adapter.

Comment: I've updated my answer... Please check and let me know that works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152750/discussion-between-nikhil-jadhav-and-samuel-robert).